# checkbox hide row when click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, show-hide

I'm having trouble with trying to hide a row when clicking the checkbox. The problem is that disappears when click and I want to show it when click. Can anybody tell me whats the problem?

I have this JavaScript code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
                if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
                    $(".red").toggle();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

and this html code:

```
<div class="custom-checkbox-holder">
    <label><input class="custom-checkbox" type="checkbox"  value="red"><span>Devuelvo el auto en otra ciudad</span></label>
</div>
<div class="destination-field red">
    <div class=" gap-small">
        <label>Ciudad de devolución</label>
        <br />
        <input id="destination" type="text" placeholder="Dónde desea entregar el vehículo" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('.red')[$(this).is(':checked')?'hide':'show']()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to hide your `.red` element after the DOM loads:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        ///add this///
        $(".red").hide();
        //////////////
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
                $(".red").toggle();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: @Fora, your welcome. If this answers your question, please Accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, `hide` / `show` `.red` depending on the status of your checkbox:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
            $('.red')[$(this).is(':checked')?'hide':'show'](); // Show / hide depending on checkbox status
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a css class and `.toggleClass('hide')` instead of `.toggle()`.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y12kta1g/)

Comment: What benefit does this have?

Comment: It would just use css instead of JS. I found this online to show a comparison of using toggleClass() vs toggle(). Not sure if it exactly fits this case though. http://jsperf.com/jquery-toggle-elements-vs-toggleclass-css-toggling/2

Answer (score 0):

On document ready keep the status of checkbox checked/unchecked base on `.red` visibility:

```js
 $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
   $(".red").toggle($(this).prop("checked"));
 });

 $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", $(".red").is(":visible"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-checkbox-holder">
  <label>
    <input class="custom-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="red"><span>Devuelvo el auto en otra ciudad</span>

  </label>
</div>
<div class="destination-field red">
  <div class=" gap-small">
    <label>Ciudad de devolución</label>
    <br />
    <input id="destination" type="text" placeholder="Dónde desea entregar el vehículo" />
  </div>
</div>
```